# how to get multiple column from python numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multiple-columns

I have a numpy array as "data". I want to retrieve all its field except the 6th field. Currently I am using following code:

```
x = data[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]]
```

which is solving the purpose, but I feel it is not the correct way.

I tried many other ways to do it, like:

```
   x = data[:, [:,6 and 7,:]],  
   x = data[:, [:,6 or 7,:]], etc
```

but nothing seems to be working.

I also checked at several other places, but could not find any solution.
Please suggest some easy way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For a more general answer (if you need to discard several columns):

```
import numpy
x =  numpy.array(data)[:,range(0,6)+range(7,18)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`numpy.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) function returns a new array with the specified columns deleted, along whichever axis you want.  The following is equivalent to the first statement you posted above:

```
x = numpy.delete(data, 6, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
cols = range(0, 18)
cols.remove(6)
x = data[:, cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be: (using list comprehension)

```
x = data[:,[index for index in range(18) if index not in [6]]]
```

which is easily scalable too, by adding more values.